# Do Buddhas have any awareness at all?

Tags: mahayana, vajrayana

I am asking moreso the mahayana/Vajrayana view as I know the theravada one.
do buddhas have any functional kind of awareness at all,or are they inert like rocks?a mahayanika told me that Buddhas have no awareness at all and no contact.yet another told me they have limited awareness.a Vajrayanika said they have jnana but not vijnana,wich would mean theyre inert and percieve nothing at all.

Comment: How is this different from https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39710/do-beings-go-into-total-unconsciousness-before-attaining-buddhahood?r=SearchResults ?

Comment: it's not the same question, that question asks about BEFORE enlightenment @AndreiVolkov

Comment: I can read too :) however please read the question body not just the title