# How is a Buddha interacting if he doesn’t have perception?

Tags: mahayana

In Mahayana literature,it is said that a Buddha has no sense perception and thus no consciousness.how can he interact with the world and create pure lands then?

Comment: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39862/do-buddhas-have-any-awareness-at-all

Comment: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39710/do-beings-go-into-total-unconsciousness-before-attaining-buddhahood

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113280/discussion-on-question-by-johny-man-how-is-a-buddha-interacting-if-he-doesnt-ha).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand but we can try to... Perception is Anatta... it is not me,mine or myself. That which is not yours ,will you cling to it? Will you crave for it ? No . Therefore by not clinging to Perception Buddha achieved cessation of perception. It does not mean perception looses its property of impermanence...Perception arises, changes and vanishes but there is no clinging to it.

Answer (score 0):

Even Buddha had the universal mental states including perception.
However, when they are in Nirodha Samapatthi, they do not have consciousness.

===================

The universal mental factors. There are seven mental factors which are called universals because they are common to every state of consciousness. **Two are feeling and perception** mentioned above. The order in which the other five are given has no sequential significance as they all co-exist in any state of consciousness. They are:

-Contact (phassa), the coming together of the sense organ, object, and appropriate consciousness.
Concentration (ekaggataa), the mental focus on one object to the exclusion of all other objects.
-Attention (manasikaara), the mind's spontaneous turning to the object which binds the associated mental factors to it.
-Psychic life (jiivitindriya), the vital force supporting and maintaining the other mental factors.
-Volition (cetanaa)

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html

Answer (score 0):

The Sublime Buddha, good householder, the Tathāgata, does not inter-act, at first place, but acts just, Such. Called often Bhagavata transports this well, often translated in it's meaning "one who really gives" or "the Liberal".

This might help to uproot a main pillar of the unclearency.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades, but for escape from this wheel, a gift]*

Answer (score 0):

I attempt to answer on similar question as below

> ```
> unconsciousness state of an individual
> ```

The title of the Sutra is "Prajnaparamita" 般若波羅蜜 which means Supreme Consciousness so how can it be unconsciousness

[Request for explanation on heart sutta](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/request-for-explanation-on-heart-sutta)